# Php form with 2 stage response and approval

Tags: php

I want to create a form in php where customer completes it. Its sent to the shop. Shop provides answer and goes back to the customer. Customer approves it and then shop proposes refund in stage 2. Customer can reject refund as too low. It would go back to the shop.
What would be the best way to write it in php?

I don't know really where to start so I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: (1) Try using a chatting / messaging system (between CS and customers) -i.e. customer can post messages (with a subject), CS can reply, and can repeat the process unlimited time (and also keeping records), because the "refund negotiation" may take several times (not just 2-stage in real life, right?), and also such a system can serve other purposes. (2) Your question (asking for "best way" / grateful for any suggestions) is , strictly speaking, opinion-based  / seeking recommendation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read here on how you can read a minimal reproducible example. It would be great for you to have some code written, so we can try to help you out :)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not tag with Javascript, I'll focus on HTML and PHP.

## Page 1

```
<form action="my/shop" method="POST">
    <!-- Form elements here -->
</form
```

User fills the form and a POST request is being sent do my/shop (change the path to the correct one in your scenario). If you have `name="somename"` property for your items, then they will be sent by the post and on server-side you will be able to refer to them via `$_POST["somename"]` and the value will be the value the field has.

## shop page

On server-side you need to handle the POST request and generate the answer to the customer. Generate a form with a checkbox (`<input type="checkbox">`) for acceptance or refusal, the user will accept or refuse it and submit the form.

## finally

Your second form was also posted and you see whether the user accepted the refund and you can handle the case whatever it may be and then redirect to the appropriate page based on the choice the user made.